# could not initialize org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.provisional.UIDecoratorManager Error when trying to start a local server

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, webserver

Eclipse 3.5.0

I am adding a JBoss 4.3.0 server, i have configured it properly, but when i click on it to see its configuration i receive the next error:

Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.provisional.UIDecoratorManager
at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.cnf.ServerDecorator.getStateImage(ServerDecorator.java:142)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.cnf.ServerDecorator.getServerStateImage(ServerDecorator.java:137)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.cnf.ServerLabelProvider.getImage(ServerLabelProvider.java:76)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.extensions.SafeDelegateCommonLabelProvider.getImage(SafeDelegateCommonLabelProvider.java:106)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.findImage(NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.java:213)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.getColumnImage(NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.java:110)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.getImage(NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.java:103)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorDecoratingLabelProvider$StyledLabelProviderAdapter.getImage(NavigatorDecoratingLabelProvider.java:60)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.getImage(DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:184)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.getImage(DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:167)
at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager.updateStatusBar(CommonNavigatorManager.java:325)
at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager$1.selectionChanged(CommonNavigatorManager.java:77)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:864)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:888)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:862)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handlePostSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1175)
at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handlePostSelect(CommonViewer.java:475)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$5.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1200)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.firePostSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:251)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$5(OpenStrategy.java:245)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$3.run(OpenStrategy.java:419)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3855)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3476)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2405)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2369)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1287)
```

Any idea on how to fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is a known [Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=299485) .

Can you try using latest version [Eclipse Juno](http://www.eclipse.org/juno/)

Comment: Thanks for reply, there's no way i can upgrade to Eclipse Juno o any other, company policies :S, is there any fix o patch i can use to solve this issue?

Comment: The parent bug contains the following patch https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=152632 .  Try with that or see whether you can at least upgrade to WTP 3.1.2 from Help->Check for Updates.